# Read and write a text file at same time using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I've got a program that must read a codebar and write the read code in a text file. Every 30 seconds a thread is launched that read that file to do some operations and delete the lines already processed.

My problem is that while I'm reading the file from the main thread, it has to be able to write more lines and be read later for the thread launched every 30 seconds.

I really haven't find any sample or idea of how approach the problem. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a file as the backing store for the work to be done, how about using a [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the "live" data? You could still use a file as a log, putting in entries for when items are queued and removed from the queue in case you need to refer back to the history of actions. That way, the file only needs to be appended to and never read, unless a roll-back of some sort is required, for example your program was stopped at an inopportune moment.

Comment: An original solution. It can be very useful

Answer (score 1):

When you have a shared mutable resource like this file and multiple units accessing it, it is common to use a lock. Locks can exist within a program, but is also offered by many file systems. Lock the file when you need to access it, and release the lock when you don't need it anymore. That way only one part of your program will access the file at any given point.

Comment: Marcus is right, its a bad idea to have multiple threads accessing a resource at the same time. Use a Lock which only allows access to one thread at a time, your pc can read close that thread and then write very fast

Comment: Lock the file was the first idea but i realized that the main thread must to have priority over the file. If i'm not wrong, if i lock the file by one thread the other can't access to it until the first one finish with it, that can't happen, when the main thread need the file it has to be able to access it